# Facebook Graph API App token not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have previously been able to get the contents of my public Facebook album using the App token (dummy token shown below):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/10153617349232349?fields=images,name,likes&access_token=foomyapptoken
```

Now I get this error:

```
Unsupported get request. Object with ID '10153617349232349' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.
```

Note that this worked perfectly for two months. It stopped working yesterday. Here is the link to the album. It shows that this is a public album and that the album ID is correct:

```
https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10153617349232349
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a user album. You can only get user albums with a User Token that includes the `user_photos` permission. Make sure your Token includes that permission and is valid: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: the information is wrong then.where exactly does it say that?

Comment: "A user access token is required with the user_photos permission to view a person's albums." - not sure where you read the other text.

Comment: I made a mistake while pasting the link, here is the right one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/album

Comment: that is about albums in general. for user albums, you need a user token with user_photos, even if the album is public.

Comment: right in the next line, btw: "A user access token with user_photos permission to retrieve any albums that the session user has uploaded. "

Comment: A "user album" is a photo album of a different user. I'm trying to access my own public album, so an App Access Token should work. In fact, it worked for two months. It stopped working yesterday.

Comment: no, app access tokens do not have any relation to any user, so it will not work. not sure why it worked somehow, but you must have used a user token, or it was a bug. your own public album needs your own user token with the user_photos permission.